# Why passing javascript promise to `then` results in strange behavior?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In [es6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) it's stated that passing non-callable to promise `then` will set promise "on fulfilled" handler into "identity". In [another section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereaction-records) of specification it's stated that "identity" is a function that evaluates to given value. According to what specification says I assume that this code:

```
Promise.resolve("foo").then(Promise.resolve("bar")).then(v => console.log(v))
```

be equal to this code:

```
Promise.resolve("foo").then(v => Promise.resolve("bar")).then(v => console.log(v))
```

But if both code samples are executed in latest Chrome or Firefox, the first one outputs "foo" and second outputs "bar". Where have I misunderstood the specification?

Comment: You're confusing passing a promise to `then` (your first example), vs. passing a function which returns a promise (your second example). The first does nothing according to the spec, since `then` ignores all non-function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the ECMAScript-6's [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereaction-records),

> If [[Handler]] is **"Identity"** it is equivalent to a function that simply returns its first argument.

So, you can think of `Identity` as the following Arrow function

```
(first) => first
```

---

So, your promise chain

```
Promise.resolve("foo").then(Promise.resolve("bar")).then(v => console.log(v))
```

effectively becomes

```
Promise.resolve("foo").then((first) => first).then(v => console.log(v))
```

That is why you are getting `foo`.